# How to get to SOP and POS form from SIGMA expression?

Tags: digital-logic

I have the following expression:

[image]

How do I get to an unreduced (i.e. don't use k-map) `Sum of products` and `Product of sums` expressions?

Answer (score 1):

The Sigma denotes an alternative, compact expression of a K-Map, more specifically the sum of the minterms, thus the sigma (sum).

What you need to know is how a given minterm X maps onto the K-Map.  [Here](http://www.allaboutcircuits.com/vol_4/chpt_8/9.html) is a summary that will get you going.

Answer (score 1):

A way to get the *unreduced* sets you seek *without using a k-map* would be to first write out the truth table for this, from which you can trivially deduce the raw SoP (sum of products) form. Then de Morgan's law can be applied to convert this to the PoS (product of sums) form (not as trivial but it's good practice).

[Some more detail on these can be found here for example](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/9817/how-to-convert-an-expression-from-sop-to-pos-and-back-in-boolean-algebra?rq=1), and of course there are various calculators out there, but the point of whatever exercise you're doing is to learn what SoP and PoS *mean*, how to apply de Morgan's laws properly and in all that get a better handle on Boolean Algebra. Hopefully this helps.