# Converting SOP to POS form

Tags: digital-logic, boolean-algebra

The boolean function I want to convert is: F = xy' + yz'

I will first convert it to canonical form:

F = xy' + yz' ------> (1)

= xy'(z + z') + (x + x')yz'

= xy'z + xy'z' + xyz' + x'yz'

= Σ(2, 4, 5, 6) = π(0, 1, 3, 7)

Now, F' = π(2, 4, 5, 6) (Is this statement correct, why not?)

= (x + y' + z)(x' + y + z)(x' + y + z')(x' + y' + z) ------> (2)

I thought I had converted the function to POS form, but when I checked the truth tables for (1) and (2), they are the complete opposite. [Truth table for 1](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=truth%20table%20%28x%20and%20not%20y%29%20or%20%28y%20and%20not%20z%29)
[Truth table for 2](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=truth%20table%20%28X%20OR%20NOT%20Y%20OR%20Z%29%20AND%20%28NOT%20X%20OR%20Y%20OR%20Z%29%20AND%20%28NOT%20X%20OR%20Y%20OR%20NOT%20Z%29AND%20%28NOT%20X%20OR%20NOT%20Y%20OR%20Z%29)

Why is this incorrect? According to [this answer](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/83230/241853), I'll have to complement the input function twice to convert to POS form. But this seems very counter-intuitive because if I complement a function twice, will I not get back the original function?

Comment: This explains it far more thoroughly.
https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/9817/how-to-convert-an-expression-from-sop-to-pos-and-back-in-boolean-algebra

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, you don't simply complement twice.

You complement once, then use DeMorgan's theorem and the distributive property to get a SOP form for \$\overline{F}\$. Complement again, and use DeMorgan's theorem again to finally get the POS form.

In a sense, you do have the original equation back again because the result is **logically equivalent** to the original equation.

Comment: Clarification- you do ultimately complement twice, but not just complement twice, also use each complement to apply DeMorgan's law first then again.